# Lookup Azure AD from Azure Data Factory (ADF)

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-logic-apps, azure-powershell, azure-data-factory

I am getting an ID from a flat file(which I believe is domainname\loginname). Before processing it to the database, I need to lookup on the Azure AD to get more details like Name, Email etc.

I need to first determine what attribute in Azure AD am I getting in my file. 
Then, I need to lookup Azure AD to get remaining additional info of that user using the ID I am getting in my flat file source.

How do I get a list of all attributes I can get from Azure AD? When I am using Get-AzureADUser powershell cmdlet on Azure portal, it is returning only object_id, email and display_name.

I am moving the file to Azure SQL DB using an ADF pipeline. I am looking for a way to lookup Azure AD from Azure Data Factory pipeline. If that is not possible ,is there any way to achieve the same using LogicApps/powershell/O365?

Answer (score 0):

I believe if you are using the azuread powershell module, then it actually does return on all the attributes. you just have to list them. eg.

```
get-azureaduser | fl
```

you should see a full list of all the attributes.

you can create a pipeline to query the o365 graph api, this should be able to get you all the data. You do this by creating an office365 connector in the pipelines then get the data.

Comment: Thanks, your powershell cmd helpted me get a list of all attributes and I was able to find the name of the one I am looking for. 
When I tried using O365 connector, there is a limitation saying that it can only copied to a storage account with service principal authentication. I was thinking if we could query the O365 connector based on a column in the source file. Can you tell how it can be queried from data factory if not possible from Copy activity?
Thanks